# Как обьяснить это выражение ++*P--?

Tags: c, указатели, операторы, стандарт, приоритет

Вопрос такой, мы знаем, что Р это поинтер на любую клетку в массиве

Нужно обьяснить значение этого выражения

```
++*P--;
```

Хочется сказать, что как будто сначала мы передвигаем поинтер на один вперед потом на один назад и как будто ничего не должно поменяться.

Но как то это было бы слишком просто.

Вопрос, верно я думаю или это не так?

Comment: Вам уже ответили, но я бы сказал кратко 2 вещи. 1) -- в этом выражении относится к указателю, а ++ к памяти, которую он адресует; 2) в своих программах *никогда не пишите ничего похожего* (в крайнем случае, помните -- `запас скобок не ограничен`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Открываем таблицу приоритетов и видим, что постдекремент имеет больший приоритет, чем прединкремент, и чем разыменование.

Значит, сначала указатель `P` уменьшится, но вернется его прежнее значение, которое будет разыменовано, а к разыменованному значению (к тому элементу, на который до этого выражения указывал `p`) будет применен оператор `++`. Возвращено будет измененное значение элемента массива.

Почему сначала разыменовано, а потом `++`, если их приоритеты одинаковы? Потому что *унарные операторы правоассоциативны*, т.е. выполняются справа налево. Никакого "на усмотрение компилятора" тут нет...

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int a[5] = { 0, 2, 4, 6, 8 };
    int * p = a + 2;

    for(int i: a) cout << i << "  "; cout << endl;
    cout << ++*p-- << endl;
    for(int i: a) cout << i << "  "; cout << endl;
    cout << ++*p-- << endl;
    for(int i: a) cout << i << "  "; cout << endl;
}
```

[Как видно](https://ideone.com/xRLzsX) по выводу

```
0  2  4  6  8  
5
0  2  5  6  8  
3
0  3  5  6  8
```

меняется и массив, и указатель - как предсказано...

Answer (score 0):

[Смотрите приоритеты](https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). Сначала однозначно постдекремент к адресу указателя, затем, на усмотрение компилятора, разыменование указателя и прединкремент или обратное.
Обрамите скобками необходимый порядок: `++(*P--);`

Comment: Унарные операторы правоассоциативны, так что никакого "на усмотрение компилятора" - разве что компилятор не соответствует стандарту...